# mysql 5.7, query to achieve this: Get least ID if repeating by message in sequence, order by ID

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

mysql 5.7, query to achieve this:
Get least ID if repeating by message in sequence, order by ID.

INPUT:

```
id          message
2485132     Process started
2485118     Process completed
2483660     Process started
2482165     Process started
2480689     Process started
2480686     Process completed
2479225     Process started
```

OUTPUT:

```
id          message
2485132     Process started
2485118     Process completed
2480689     Process started
2480686     Process completed
2479225     Process started
```

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life in three months. I would strongly suggest you update to 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you want to bring the "last" record in each group of consecutive rows having the same message.

Here is one way to solve it in MySQL 5.x with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not t.message <=> (
    select t1.message from mytable t1 where t1.id < t.id order by t1.id desc limit 1
)
order by id desc
```

Basically, the subquery returns the status on the "previsous" row; if it is different from the status on the current row, then we retain the row, else we discard it.

| id | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2485132 | Process started |
| 2485118 | Process completed |
| 2480689 | Process started |
| 2480686 | Process completed |
| 2479225 | Process started |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z3-X-31J)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
                  AND t1.message <> t2.message
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM table t3
    WHERE t1.id < t3.id
      AND t3.id < t2.id
    )
```

Comment: Looks like this is not giving exactly the expected results: https://dbfiddle.uk/Yp5_5Fdz. The third row should have id `2480689` instead of `2483660`.

Comment: @GMB True. I solve another task - to return not earliest but closest process starting point. For to fix it's enough to replace all `<` with `>`. https://dbfiddle.uk/HaXTytn_